# Calculating Lagrangian of electromagnetism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, maxwell-equations, variational-calculus

I know that the interaction terms of the Lagrangian of electromagnetism are given by

$$L_{int}=-q\phi (\mathbf{x},t)+q\mathbf{v}(t)\cdot \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x},t).$$

The above equation is replaced by terms involving a continuous charge density $\rho$ and current density $\mathbf{j}$. The resulting Lagrangian density for the electromagnetic field is:
$$\mathcal{L}=-\rho \phi +\mathbf{j}\cdot \mathbf{A}＋\frac{\epsilon _{0}}{2}E^{2}-\frac{1}{2\mu _{0}}B^{2}
.$$

The first problem is that I know where the first two terms $-\rho \phi +\mathbf{j}\cdot \mathbf{A}$ come from but I don't know where the last two terms $\frac{\epsilon _{0}}{2}E^{2}-\frac{1}{2\mu _{0}}B^{2}$ come from.

Next varying the Lagrangian density with respect to $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$, we get Gauss' law
$$0=-\rho +\epsilon _{0}\triangledown \cdot \mathbf{E}$$
and Ampère's law
$$0=\mathbf{j}+\epsilon _{0}\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}-\frac{1}{\mu _{0}}\triangledown \times \mathbf{B},$$
respectively.
The second problem is that I don't know how to calculate these variations clearly.

Comment: 1. Lagrangians are not derived. They are constructed such that they yield the correct equations of motion. 2. The second part of your question seems to just be how to derive the Euler-Lagrange equations, which is explained in many places.

Comment: @ACuriousMind yes I know that Lagrangian is not derived, but my problem is how to transfer Lagrangian to Lagrangian density.

Comment: Then what exactly do you mean by your "first problem"?

Comment: ＠ACuriousMind I know what the Euler-Lagrange equation is, but what bothers me is the technical detail

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3005/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34241/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51169/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64272/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Although late in the party, take a look in my answer here :  **Deriving Lagrangian density for electromagnetic field** ( http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34241/deriving-lagrangian-density-for-electromagnetic-field/270950#270950 ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from the original (obviously scalar) Langrangian

You started with this term $$-{\frac {1}{4\mu _{0}}}F_{\mu \nu }F_{\rho \sigma }\eta ^{\mu \rho }\eta ^{\nu \sigma }$$

Which reduces to

$$=-{\frac {1}{4\mu _{0}}}F_{\mu \nu }F^{\mu \nu }$$

You need to take account of the fact that the E and B fields can be written in terms of the Faraday  tensor $${\displaystyle F_{\mu \nu }}$$ We define this tensor as:

$${\displaystyle F_{\mu \nu }=\partial _{\mu }A_{\nu }-\partial _{\nu }A_{\mu }}$$

Which in turn reduces the above to:

$$={\displaystyle {\epsilon _{0} \over 2}{E}^{2}-{1 \over {2\mu _{0}}}{B}^{2}}$$

The derivation of the two inhomogeneous Maxwell equations also derives from

$${\displaystyle \partial _{\mu }F^{\mu \nu }=\mu _{0}J^{\nu }}$$

Now you can write  Gauss's law and Ampère's  law using the following replacements :

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}{\frac {1}{c}}E^{i}&=-F^{0i}\\\epsilon ^{ijk}B_{k}&=-F^{ij}\end{aligned}}}$$

where i, j, k range through 1, 2, and 3