# Variation of electromagnetic action to obtain Maxwell's equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, maxwell-equations, variational-calculus

The electromagnetic action is given in the language of differential forms by
$$S[A]=-\frac{1}{4}\int F\wedge \star F$$
The variation of the electromagnetic action $S$ gives us Maxwell's equations
$$d\star F=0.$$

---

How do you take the variation $\delta S = S[A+\delta A]-S[A]$ of the above action $S$ to obtain Maxwell's equations?

Comment: you need to compute $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\big|_{t=0}S(A+t\eta)$ where $F=\mathrm dA$ and $\eta$ arbitrary

Comment: How would you do this by taking the variation of the action?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3005/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34241/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51169/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64272/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we only consider the abelian case. Let $A\to A+\delta A$, and $F\to d(A+\delta A)=dA+d\delta A$.The action becomes

$$S[A+\delta A]=-\frac{1}{4}\int (dA+d\delta A)\wedge\star(dA+d\delta A).$$

So up to terms linear in $\delta A$, 
$$S[A+\delta A]-S[A]=\frac{1}{2}\int \delta A\wedge d(\star F)+\mathcal{O}(\delta A^2),$$
where we integrated by parts and used the symmetric property of the inner product on $p$ form $(\alpha,\beta)=\int\alpha\wedge\star\beta=\int \beta\wedge \star\alpha=(\beta,\alpha).$

Now $\frac{\delta S}{\delta A}=0$ gives you $d\star F=0$ as $\delta A$ is arbitrary.